# Java Observer and strategy combination?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I'm using a combination of the MVC pattern and Observer pattern, where my view is the observer and my model the subject with state.

Is it OK to use the Strategy Pattern for the state change in my subject/model, because there are several behaviors that I need to implement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You can implement combination of design patterns to solve your problem. I would like to highlight below points about design patterns

> - Design patterns are solutions for recurring common problems. They are guidelines to solve a particular problem.
> - You can create your own design pattern for your problem. Solving your problem is important than fitting your solution into one of existing design patterns.
> - Sometimes design patterns will limit our thinking process into available design patterns,which is not good. You should not be constrained about existing patterns
> - Design patterns are facilitators but they are not obligatory

Comment: I was thinking the same. Thank You